# Change charset in included html

Tags: html, character-encoding

I use a lot of included files and recently have some of them changed by javascript.
 My script changes the content in a div from a `*.html-file.`

The content is plain text.

But, when I change this content, the charset in this specific file change.
I normally use `ISO-8859-1`, but it changes to `UTF-8` or some.

Yes, there is a reason why I don't use UTF-8 or other ;)

I have googled a lot, but all I can find is how to use PHP, ASP, javascript to include the overall charset metas - and

how to include meta with an included file... Which is none of the problem

But how can I change the charset in this javascript included file?

Comment: Thx for the edits, but how about an answer....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Found myself an solution :)

This can be put into an existing Javascript:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend' : function(xhr) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
    },
});
```

Alternately change the charset to that you use of your own :)